# 'get_attribute' method in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

The *get_attribute()* method in Python Selenium gives an error:

> Did you mean '**getattribute**'.

Why do I need that?

I am trying to get the parent elements class attribute to know if I got to the right [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) place.

[image]

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime
#import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
element_to_click = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler") #.click()
element_to_click.click()
element_to_save = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div/div/div/div/h4")

#Element_to_save.to_excel("3row, 3column)")
f = open('result_file00.txt', 'r+')
f.write(element_to_save.text)
f.write("\n")
f.write(str(datetime.today()))
myList = []
myList.append(1)

elements_to_save = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")
for element in elements_to_save:
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(element.text)
    myList.append(element.text)
    f.write(" \n ")
    f.write(str(datetime.today()))

f.close()
f = open('result_file00.txt', 'r+')
print(f.read())
f.close()
print(myList)
print(type(myList))

time.sleep(1)
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
element_to_search = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, myList[1])
parentof_element_to_search = element_to_search.parent
print(parentof_element_to_search.get_attribute("class")) # Error-giving line

driver.quit()
```

I tried `parentof_element_to_search = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH(".."))` to get the parent element. Then trying to get the parent class of that element with `parentof_element_to_search.get_attribute("class")` resulted in the same error.

My desired code snippet from this result is getting the value of the 6-th <td> element in that <tr>.
`find_element(By.XPATH("//td[6]")`, the green line in the photo.

In brief, I get the team name's <td> line, then coming back to the same <tr> tag and getting 6 step for the <td> value.

Comment: Since this is a top search engine hit for `site:stackoverflow.com get_attribute Selenium`, [`getAttribute()` in Java](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#tabs-10-1), `get_attribute()` in Python, `GetAttribute()` in C#, `attribute()` in Ruby, `getAttribute()` in JavaScript, and `getAttribute()` in [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language))...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually getting the parent element with `parentof_element_to_search=element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH(".."))`

Try this instead:

```py
parent_of_element_to_search = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH("./.."))
```

Now you will be able to apply `get_attribute()` on it like the following:

```py
parent_of_element_to_search = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH("./.."))
parent_element_classes = parent_of_element_to_search.get_attribute("class")
```

This is what I tried:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1'
driver.get(url)

myList = []
myList.append(1)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@data-id='nba:schedule:main:team:link']")))
for element in elements:
    myList.append(element.text)


driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
element_to_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, myList[1])))
classes = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH, "./..").get_attribute("class")
print(classes)
```

And this is the output of my program run:

```
Crom_text__NpR1_ Crom_primary__EajZu StatsTeamsTraditionalTable_primary__U2_3n Crom_stickySecondColumn__29Dwf
```

Comment: it gives an error `    parent_of_element_to_search=element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH("./.."))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. Does it mean I need to wrap element_to_search inside str() method?

Comment: same error even with "parent_of_element_to_search=element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH("//parent::tr[1]"))"

Comment: Please see my updated answer and let me see what am I missing

Comment: please run after `time.sleep(1)` you run the first url, there I take team name.put it inside list. Then I run `time.sleep(1)
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")` where inside table I search for team name

Comment: in your loop you should take team names inside loop then search for one of them inside another url page

Comment: OK, please see the updated answer

Comment: you get the <td class. That's really great. I will need to get one node parent to <tr. But, please give me time to digest comprehend. In my code when I get class of `element_to_search` it gives me two parent nodes Anchor_anchor__cSc3P. That's wrong, the ,span element is inside <div then it is inside <anchor,(then <td you found....I am lost

Comment: As I see `tr` do not have class attribute. Also, you can locate the parent based on the child node, not by getting up with `/..`

Comment: I tried to get from your code to there gives an error `driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/traditional")
element_to_search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, myList[1])))
classes = element_to_search.find_element(By.XPATH, "./..")
class_parent_tr = classes.find_element(By.XPATH, "./..")
result=class_parent_tr.find_element(By.XPATH("//td[6]"))
print(result.text)
driver.quit`

Comment: Moment. So, is it working for you now and the problem is resolved or you getting an error?

Comment: Your code works well! Just the final result does not give me what I want. My main destination is to get in same <tr line to the 6th <td